# What are the app name restrictions for Android and iPhone apps?

Tags: android, iphone, google-play, app-store-connect, itunes-store

What are the rules for the actual name of the application? Can it have dots? For instance, is "MyDomain.com" a valid app name?

If dots are allowed, then can I register an application under a domain name that I do not own? 
For instance, "SomeOneElsesDomain.com"? Is it allowed considering that the domain has no app of its own so far?

Are there different rules on this for Apple/Android eco system?

Comment: Please!! check this [How to Choose a Name for Your Mobile App without Violating Trademarks](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2364-how-to-choose-a-name-for-your-mobile-app-without-violating-trademarks/) may helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I will soon :)

Comment: "How to Choose a Name for Your Mobile App without Violating Trademarks" link no longer works.

Comment: Great nice questionS.